# Can't get intent from Activity A to Activity B

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I have `ListView` populated from MySQL. So far is good and working. I have 4 rows in database and I got them. So now I'm trying when user select item from this `ListView` to open this particular item and load some more info from database. For example:

[image]

So I have first screen done and working. But now when I click on `Item 1` I get `NULL` in `LogCat`

```
11-07 11:55:30.805: W/Bundle(1393): Key id expected Integer but value was a java.lang.Long.  The default value 0 was returned.
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393): Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:1000)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.os.Bundle.getInt(Bundle.java:982)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at com.reserveme.RestaurantInformation.onCreate(UserInformation.java:53)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
11-07 11:55:30.835: W/Bundle(1393):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is what I'm trying -> `User.java` a.k.a `Activiti A`

```
public class Users extends Activity {

ListView listView;
TextView textView;
private StockAdaptor stockAdaptor;
String jsonResult = null;
ImageView image;
String info;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.users); //Just a listView, shown below
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rest_id);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
    new JsonReadTask().execute("http://link.to.site/GetUsers.php");

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(listView.getLayoutParams());
    lp.setMargins(10, 10, 0, 0);
    listView.setLayoutParams(lp);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Users.this, UserInformation.class);
            //intent.putExtra("id", position);
            intent.putExtra("id", stockAdaptor.getItemId(position));
            intent.putExtra("info", info);
            //intent.putExtra("text", text);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true; //No options
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    stockAdaptor = new StockAdaptor(this); //Create a new StockAdaptor
}

public static String strFromStream(InputStream in) throws IOException { //Simple function, getting a String from an InputStream
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader breader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
    String cline;
    String newLine = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    while ((cline = breader.readLine()) != null) {
        out.append(cline);
        out.append(newLine);
    }
    return out.toString();
}

private class StockAdaptor extends BaseAdapter { //The stocks list adaptor

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView id;
        TextView name;
        TextView info;
        ImageView image; 
    }

    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private RestaurantStrings[] stocks = null; //Array of stocks
    private ListView stocksListView = null;

    public StockAdaptor(Context context) {
        super();
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    public void setStockList(RestaurantStrings[] stocksinfo) {
        this.stocks = stocksinfo;// //////////////LITERALLY THIS

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return stocks.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return stocks[position];
    }
    public RestaurantStrings[] getAll() { //Return the array of stocks
        return stocks;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return stocks[position].id;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder; //New holder
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.users_second, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            // Creates the new viewHolder define above, storing references to the children
            holder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rest_id);
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.info);

            if (holder.image != null) {
                if (holder.image.getDrawable() == null) {
                    new ImageDownloaderTask(holder.image, null)                                 
                    .execute(stocks[position].image); //Download the image using the image

                }
            }
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {

            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        //holder.id.setText(stocks[position].id);
        holder.name.setText(stocks[position].name);
        holder.info.setText(stocks[position].info);

        return convertView;
    }
}
// some more code below ( image download, json response ... etc)
```

Here is `UserInformation` a.ka. `Activity B`

```
public class UserInformation extends Activity {

String info;
int rest_id;
TextView textView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.user_informations);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rest_id);
    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (b != null) {
        rest_id = b.getInt("id");
        textView.setText(rest_id+"");
        info = b.getString("info");
        textView.setText(info+"");
    }

 }
```

`user_information.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="50dp"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_weight="13.07"
    android:background="@drawable/restaurants_buttons"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/rest_id"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp" />


</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Currently I'll be glad to show just `Info`.

**I'm sorry for long post but I try to fix this all day and no luck. I don't know what else to do. Also may be now my code is really mess but please avoid this for now. I will try to make it better but first want to fix this.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting class cast exception because in Activity A you are putting Long value as id and you are trying to get it as integer in Activity B. Change this

```
int rest_id;
```

into

```
long rest_id;
```

and this

```
rest_id = b.getInt("id");
```

into

```
rest_id = b.getLong("id");
```

Comment: To further clarify: getItemId(position) returns a value of the primitive type long. Therefore the putExtra method called in the above code will be the putExtra(String, long) version, not the putExtra(String, int) version. Therefore trying to read a int primitive type from the bundle will throw a class cast exception.

Comment: Thank's for your answer but I got `NULL` in `Activity B` .. NULL in the `TextView`

Comment: Any ideas at all how to get info from database for that particular item?

Comment: @JasonPaddle that's probably a different problem and does not belong to the original question, I suggest you mark this question as solved first. Also the String info is never assigned when you send it to your other Activity, it will of-course then still be null.

Comment: of course you are getting the null in the textView because in Activity A you are putting a variable info into intent but this variable has never bean initialized in this activity so its value is NULL. Thats why you are getting it in TextView in Activity B. Is this info showing in your listView?

Comment: @KarolŻygłowicz, yes I see it in Activity A. Isn't is assigned here `holder.info = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.info);` `holder.info.setText(stocks[position].info);` and since is visible in Activity A? And in `.php` file I querying all info from DB..

Comment: no it's not correct because holder.info is not visible in A activity. This variable is in your BaseAdapter class. You need to get this info from your stocks array and you need to use possition variable from setOnItemClickListener method to know which one

Comment: Can you help me with this? Some example where exactly to put this?

Comment: Where are you setting the RestaurantStrings[] stocks variable?

Comment: In separate class `public class RestaurantStrings {
 public int id;
    public String name;
    public String info;
    public String image; 
    public String text;
    

}`

Comment: move RstaurantStrings[] stocks variable to A activity and make it public so it should be visible in you BaseAdapter class. Dont forget to forget to fill it with data from you php. In your setOnItemClickListener method try intent.putExtra("info", stocks[position]);

Comment: Ok, I've moved full class into activity a. Also put `intent.putExtra("info", stocks[position]);` but here `stocks` is not resolved?

Comment: move RstaurantStrings[] stocks from BaseAdapter class into Users Activity too

Comment: I don't understand that. Are you talking aboit `private RestaurantStrings[] stocks = null; //Array of stocks`? If yes, it is already in Users activity.. users is activity A

Comment: I told you before dont forget to fill stocks array with data from your php for example in onCreate of your activity. I won't tell you how because you didnt paste the code. Stocks array wasn't null in your StockAdaptor  class right? You are getting values in your ListView. Initialize this variable just like you did in StockAdaptor before but do it in UsersActivity's onCreate.

Comment: I use this from one tutorial since I'm kinda new in android and java. Which code you want to paste? That's what I can't understand since I take all the data in activity A and trying to pass with intent to activity B you tell me that I need another query to database from activity B also? PHP code is simple connection to db and query like `select * from users`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64513/discussion-between-karol-zyglowicz-and-jason-paddle).